# Sql must declare the scalar variable error

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am new to C# and could use some guidance, googling has advised of many different things, but none of which i can get to work. I have blocked out the data source details etc, but these are valid in the code

The below is my whole code when I click my "Save Button"

```
public void testLoadAuditBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 =
        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXXX; Initial Catalog=XXXXX; User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX");

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO testloadaudit (item_type,load_id,UserId, Comment, dateamended) VALUES (@item_type, @load_id, @UserId, @Comment, @dateamended)";
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

    sqlConnection1.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConnection1.Close();
}
```

Which I receive this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>        Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@item_type".

If anybody can advise of how to make the above insert into the table that would be great.

Comment: You are totally missing to add the parameters to the command collection

Comment: Clearly, you didn't add your parameters to your command. What is the value of your parameter value that you added in `@item_type` for example?

Comment: Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

Comment: @SonerGönül The value will be a variable depending what the users adds in through the windows form at the time, it will change nearly every time

Answer (score 5):

You have used parameters in your query text but haven't added them to the `SqlCommand`.

You need to add code like this for each parameter before executing your query:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@item_type", SqlDbType.????);
cmd.Parameters["@item_Type"].Value = ???
```

Where you should specify appropriate type and value for each parameter.

Comment: Hello, the value for @item_type will be a variable from the column called item_type in the database. Is there a way for the Windows Form to pick them up as variables without having to set a value?

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_type", type);

Comment: @NinoMirzaMušić `AddWithValue` method generally should be avoided. This article precisely describes the reason of it: [Can we stop using AddWithValue already](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @CSys how can be "*value for `@item_type` will be a variable from the column called item_type in the database*" if you're *inserting* this value into column specified? You have to specify - which exactly value to put in that column. How exactly you want your form to pick it for you? From what source should it pick? Try to explain your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query has parameters which expect values:

```
... VALUES (@item_type, @load_id, @UserId, @Comment, @dateamended)
```

So you need to supply those values.  What are you actually *inserting* into the database?  The values you supply determine that.  For example:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_type", "some value");
```

Comment: Hi David, the users will not be entering the same value every time that is my problem. I have a list of just over 12,000 unique codes that will could be entered into the form as the @item_type. So it needs to be whatever the user has entered as the value when typing into the form, if this helps?

Comment: @CSys: Well, use the value that the user entered of course.

Comment: What would need to be entered in the above instead of "some value" to make it pick up what the user inserts? Sorry this is about 4 hours in using Visual Studio to try and understand, so I am struggling

Comment: @CSys: It really sounds like you should probably start with some tutorials on .NET development.  Wherever you're getting the user input, that's what you would use in your query parameter.  Maybe it's in a variable somewhere, maybe it's in a form control, etc.  It's really up to you where you're storing values in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the parameters like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { Name = "@item_type", SqlDbType =  /* Use your DB Type here */, Value = /* Add your value here */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not added actual [parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) values for your query. You can add it with [`SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO testloadaudit (item_type,load_id,UserId, Comment, dateamended) VALUES (@item_type, @load_id, @UserId, @Comment, @dateamended)";
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_type", yourActualItemTypeValue);
// add here values for each other parameters
sqlConnection1.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```